# org-capture notes above footnotes header?

Tags: org-mode, org-capture

Org-capture appends its notes to the bottom of my notes.org file. But this places them below the `* Footnotes` headline, which is problematic. Is there some way to configure `org-capture` so new notes are sent above the `* Footnotes` headline?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The best option here would be to configure your capture templates to add entries under a certain heading (e.g Tasks or Notes). That way the other content of the target file is not affected. See the examples in the [Org manual](http://orgmode.org/manual/Capture-templates.html#Capture-templates):

```
("t" "Todo" entry (file+headline "~/org/gtd.org" "Tasks")
         "* TODO %?\n  %i\n  %a")
```

Another option would be to customize `org-reverse-note-order` so that new entries are added at the top of the file rather than the end.